# find records for user that are not contiguous

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am having trouble figuring out how to even start this query.

I have a table that has the following columns and data:

```
User   BeginMile EndMile
1         1        5
1         5        6
1         6        20
1         20       25
1         25       29
2         1         9
2         15        20
3         1         2
3         6         10
3         10        12
```

I need to first find where there are gaps for each user from the EndMile of the previous record, to the BeginMile of the next record. I then need to return the record before and after where the gap occurs for each user.

In the previous data example, I would like the following returned:

```
User   PrevBeginMile   PrevEndMile    AfterBeginMile AfterEndMile   Gap
2         1                9                15          20           6
3         1                2                6           10           4
```

How can this be done?

Comment: BeginDate and EndDate? Do you mean BeginMile and EndMile?

Comment: Whoops. Edited to Begin/EndMile

Comment: How are you ordering your table?

Comment: It can just be ordered by User,BeginMile,EndMile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you're on SQL 2005, this should work:

```
DECLARE @Runners TABLE (Id INT, BeginMile INT, EndMile INT)

INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (1,1,5)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (1,5,6)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (1,6,20)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (1,20,25)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (1,25,29)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (2,1,9)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (2,15,20)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (3,1,2)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (3,6,10)
INSERT INTO @Runners VALUES (3,10,12)

WITH OrderedUsers AS (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY BeginMile) RowNum
    FROM    @Runners
)

SELECT  a.Id [User]
,   a.BeginMile PrevBeginMile
,   a.EndMile PrevEndMile
,   b.BeginMile AfterBeginMile
,   b.EndMile AfterEndMile
,   b.BeginMile - a.EndMile Gap
FROM    OrderedUsers a
JOIN    OrderedUsers b
ON  a.Id = b.Id
AND a.EndMile <> b.BeginMile
AND a.RowNum = b.RowNum - 1
```

Comment: I'd replace the two sub-queries with a CTE...  `;WITH ordered_table AS (<sub-query>) SELECT blah FROM ordered_table AS a INNER JOIN ordered_table AS b ON blah-de-blah`

Comment: @Dems - Good suggestion.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using RowNumber() [as in other answers], you could use...

```
SELECT
  [current].User,
  [current].BeginMile                   AS [PrevBeginMile],
  [current].EndMile                     AS [PrevEndMile],
  [next].BeginMile                      AS [AfterBeginMile],
  [next].EndMile                        AS [AfterEndMile],
  [next].BeginMile - [current].EndMile  AS [Gap]
FROM
  myTable AS [current]
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable WHERE user = [current].User AND BeginMile > [current].BeginMile ORDER BY BeginMile ASC) AS [next]
WHERE
 [current].EndMile <> [next].BeginMile
```

Or possibly...

```
FROM
  myTable AS [current]
INNER JOIN
  myTable AS [next]
    ON  [next].BeginMile != [current].EndMile
    AND [next].BeginMile  = (
                             SELECT
                               MIN(BeginMile)
                             FROM
                               myTable
                             WHERE
                               user = [current].User
                               AND BeginMile > [current].BeginMile
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
WITH acte(user,beginmile,endmile) AS
(
SELECT user,start,end
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY START ASC) rownum
FROM mytable
)
SELECT base.user,base.beginmile,base.endmile,base.BeginMile - lead.EndMile Gap 
FROM acte base 
LEFT JOIN acte lead on base.id=lead.id AND base.rownum=lead.rownum-1
WHERE base.BeginMile - lead.EndMile > 0
```